# SQL parameterized? I'm lost

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have no idea how to use parameterized and would like someone to point me into the right direction.

Here's what I'm currently using.

```
Public Class main
Dim dbCon As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=payid;Uid=root")
Dim strQuery As String = ""
Dim SQLCmd As MySqlCommand
Dim DR As MySqlDataReader
Private Sub Use()
    Try
        strQuery = "UPDATE payid " & _
            "SET used='" & amen.Text & "' " & _
             "WHERE payid='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

        SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        dbCon.Open()
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If someone could change that for me I'd be able to do the rest of my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/1070452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strQuery = "UPDATE payid SET used=@used WHERE payid=@payid "
SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@used", amen.Text)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payid", TextBox1.Text )
```

Comment: Just a notice. Do you use the same name for all Database, table and field?? (payid)

Comment: Yeah, should it be changed? Also, im getting: Error'Parameters' is not a member of 'String'